# Mongoose hangs forever when replica set is not given

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here's a way to connect to a mongodb replica set with mongoose:

```
var connectionString = 'mongodb://user:password@primary:27017,secondary1:27017,secondary2:27017/dbName?authMecanism=MONGODB-CR&replicaSet=mySet';
var options = { useMongoClient: true };
mongoose.connect(connectionString, options, error => {
    if (error) throw error;
    console.log('database on');
});
```

If I give the wrong credentials, this connection will fail.

If I give the wrong IPs, any query will end up in a ETIMEDOUT.

However if I remove the `replicaSet` get parameter in the connection string, any "find" query will run forever: it won't time out and won't enter the callback either.

Is there any event to listen to in this case?

PS: I don't know if this is relevant but I'm using mongo 3.3 with mongoose 4.11.

Comment: You have a different problem to the one you think you have. For instance I regularly connect to replica set members without providing such a parameter to the connection and do not have this problem. Sounds more like you actually have the wrong addresses still. Bottom line is that the database connection will not actually be made or has been lost after connection. The latter seems more likely. Also your really "minalimist" callback on the connection makes me think that you don't actually handle this property. The intent is to "wrap" your app logic in that callback or await in modern syntax

Comment: @NeilLunn You might have noticed this is a sample code and not actual code. I usually handle the error, the point is the callback isn't called when I don't provide the replica set parameter and the database works fine when it is.

Comment: *"You might have noticed this is a sample code..."*. No actually, and I would never make such presumptions. Nor should I and nor should you. In fact it is completely **the opposite** of what is the prescribed way to ask questions here and to diagnose your problems. Please look at and indeed "follow the example from"  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you want to come here and say *"Things don't work when I do this..."* then you had better come armed with a reproducible case. Otherwise it's not something anyone can reproduce.

Comment: @NeilLunn by "sample code" I meant it's the test case with the minimal options that I managed to isolate while still reproducing the problem :) It's definitely reproducible on my side. If you tell me that you can omit the "replicaSet" parameter and it'll still work, I'm interested but that's not the case on my side.